# Cannot deploy MFP v6.3 adapters and apps with MFP CLI v7.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

**Context:**
We developed an app using MFP v6.3. Using MFP CLI v6.3, we can restart, build and deploy all assets (WAR, adapters, and apps) without any problems.

**Problem:** 
Using MFP CLI v7.0 to deploy the MFP v6.3 adapters and apps is not working. Below, I am including most of the from executing 'mfp restart'; note that the exit code is 1. I also included the output of 'mfp bd'. It seems the only MFP asset that gets deployed is the WAR file; MFP adapters and apps are not deployed. Bringing the MFP console also confirms this.

**MFP CLI v7.0 restart output:**

```
$ mfp restart -d
[...]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dbasedir=/Users/olivieri/git/Ready.App.4.Perch/PerchReadyApp
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.jars.dir=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.ant.tools.dir=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/ant-tools
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.hostname=192.168.1.126
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -file=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml
mobilefirst-cli verb ant task install-admin
Buildfile: /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml

install-admin
[...]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dbasedir=/Users/olivieri/git/Ready.App.4.Perch/PerchReadyApp
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.jars.dir=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.ant.tools.dir=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/ant-tools
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.hostname=192.168.1.126
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -file=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml
mobilefirst-cli verb ant task install-WAR
Buildfile: /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml

install-WAR:
[configureapplicationserver] Logging output of task <configureApplicationServer> to file /Users/olivieri/.mobilefirst_platform_server/configuration-logs/configureApplicationServer_2015_06_17_23_46_28.log
[configureapplicationserver] ** Creating migrated war file
[configureapplicationserver] Jun 17, 2015 11:46:29 PM com.worklight.ant.migration.MigrationTask MigrationTask.execute
[configureapplicationserver] INFO: FWLST2014I: The migration process was bypassed, because the project WAR file of version 7.0.0.00.20150608-1356 is compatible with the server version 7.0.0.00.20150608-1356.
[configureapplicationserver] Jun 17, 2015 11:46:29 PM com.worklight.ant.migration.MigrationTask MigrationTask.execute
[configureapplicationserver] INFO: FWLST2015I: The project WAR file was successfully copied to the destination location '/var/folders/c9/gf_f0_sd60q1mm9kxwgvlxsr0000gn/T/wla3231324120/PerchReadyApp.war'.
[configureapplicationserver] ** Created migrated war file
[configureapplicationserver] Copying /var/folders/c9/gf_f0_sd60q1mm9kxwgvlxsr0000gn/T/wla3231324120/derby.jar to /Users/olivieri/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.0.0.00.20150608-1356/server/wlp/usr/shared/resources/PerchReadyApp/derby/derby.jar
[configureapplicationserver] Copying /Users/olivieri/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.0.0.00.20150608-1356/server/wlp/usr/servers/worklight/server.xml to /Users/olivieri/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.0.0.00.20150608-1356/server/wlp/usr/servers/worklight/server.xml.bak16
[configureapplicationserver] Modifying /Users/olivieri/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.0.0.00.20150608-1356/server/wlp/usr/servers/worklight/server.xml
[configureapplicationserver] Copying /var/folders/c9/gf_f0_sd60q1mm9kxwgvlxsr0000gn/T/wla3231324120/PerchReadyApp.war to /Users/olivieri/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.0.0.00.20150608-1356/server/wlp/usr/servers/worklight/apps/PerchReadyApp.war

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
objc[22452]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Starting server worklight.
Server worklight started with process ID 22451.
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dbasedir=/Users/olivieri/git/Ready.App.4.Perch/PerchReadyApp
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.jars.dir=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.ant.tools.dir=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/ant-tools
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.hostname=192.168.1.126
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -file=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml
mobilefirst-cli verb ant task upgrade
Buildfile: /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml

upgrade:
[project-upgrader] FINE: DEBUG_PERFORM_UPGRADE
[project-upgrader] INFO: FWLST1022I: Starting to migrate the PerchReadyApp project from version 6.3.0.00.20150214-1702 to version 7.0.0.00.20150608-1356.
[project-upgrader] INFO: FWLPL0025I: The PerchReadyApp project is being saved as /Users/olivieri/git/Ready.App.4.Perch/PerchReadyApp/PerchReadyApp_2015_06_17_234645.backup.zip file.
[project-upgrader] path found:6.3.0.0--->7.0.0.0
[project-upgrader] FINE: DEBUG_FOUND_PATH
[project-upgrader] INFO: FWLST1226I: Added Authorization Manager Cordova plugin to config.xml (/Users/olivieri/git/Ready.App.4.Perch/PerchReadyApp/apps/Perch/iphone/native/config.xml).
[project-upgrader] FINE: DEBUG_STAMP_VERSION
[project-upgrader] WARN: FWLST1118W: Native libraries in application 'Perch' were upgraded. It is recommended to deploy this app with a new version to the WL Server and also publish a new version in the App Store for the environment(s): iphone. Clients with older SDKs will no longer receive direct update. You may want to block/notify older versions to enforce the customers to upgrade to a newer version from the app store.
[project-upgrader] INFO: FWLPL0018I: Migrating the PerchReadyApp project from version 6.3.0.00.20150214-1702 to version 7.0.0.00.20150608-1356 has succeeded.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 20 seconds
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.ant.tools.dir=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/ant-tools
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.hostname=192.168.1.126
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -file=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml
mobilefirst-cli verb ant task build-All
Buildfile: /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml

build-All:

build-WAR:
     [echo] Building worklight WAR for project PerchReadyApp
[war-builder] Ignoring contents of 'server/java' folder. To include this folder, set the 'compileJava' property to true. 
[war-builder] Building war: /Users/olivieri/git/Ready.App.4.Perch/PerchReadyApp/bin/PerchReadyApp.war

build-Adapters:
     [echo] Build MobileFirst adapters for project PerchReadyApp
     [echo] Building MobileFirst Adapter /Users/olivieri/git/Ready.App.4.Perch/PerchReadyApp/adapters/AuthenticationAdapter
     [echo] Worklight Ant task version 7.0.0.00.20150608-1356
[adapter-builder] Building zip: /Users/olivieri/git/Ready.App.4.Perch/PerchReadyApp/bin/AuthenticationAdapter.adapter
     [echo] Building MobileFirst Adapter /Users/olivieri/git/Ready.App.4.Perch/PerchReadyApp/adapters/DBSetupAdapter
     [echo] Worklight Ant task version 7.0.0.00.20150608-1356
[adapter-builder] Building zip: /Users/olivieri/git/Ready.App.4.Perch/PerchReadyApp/bin/DBSetupAdapter.adapter
     [echo] Building MobileFirst Adapter /Users/olivieri/git/Ready.App.4.Perch/PerchReadyApp/adapters/PerchAdapter
     [echo] Worklight Ant task version 7.0.0.00.20150608-1356
[adapter-builder] Building zip: /Users/olivieri/git/Ready.App.4.Perch/PerchReadyApp/bin/PerchAdapter.adapter

build-Apps:
     [echo] Build MobileFirst apps for project PerchReadyApp
     [echo] Building Hybrid MobileFirst App /Users/olivieri/git/Ready.App.4.Perch/PerchReadyApp/apps/Perch
     [echo] Worklight Ant task version 7.0.0.00.20150608-1356
[app-builder] Jun 17, 2015 11:47:08 PM com.worklight.ant.builders.ApplicationBuilderTask execute
[app-builder] SUCCESS: FWLST2001I: Successfully built environments: [common, iphone]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 4 seconds
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dbasedir=/Users/olivieri/git/Ready.App.4.Perch/PerchReadyApp
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.jars.dir=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.ant.tools.dir=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/ant-tools
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.hostname=192.168.1.126
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -file=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml
mobilefirst-cli verb ant task runtime-status
Buildfile: /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml

runtime-status:
    [wladm] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    [wladm] <runtime name="PerchReadyApp" numberOfAdapters="0" numberOfApplications="0" synchronizationStatus="ok" numberOfActiveDevices="0" numberOfDecommissionedDevices="0" isDeviceTabEnabled="true" isAccessManagementEnabled="false" analyticsConsolePath="http://192.168.1.126:10080/analytics/console" bitlyApiKey="" bitlyUsername="" platformVersion="7.0.0.00.20150608-1356" serverVersion="7.0.0.00.20150608-1356" developmentMode="true" deviceTrackingEnabled="true" running="true" auditEnabled="true" topology="STANDALONE" productVersion="7.0.0.00-20150608-1356">
    [wladm]   <license numberOfActiveDevices="0" numberOfInactiveDevices="0" numberOfApplications="0" numberOfServers="0" lastReportDate="2015-06-18T04:43:10.546Z" decommissionTaskInterval="86400" decommissionWhen="90" maxNumberOfRecordedDevices="0" maxNumberOfRecordedDevicesOnDate="2015-06-18T04:31:50.030Z" archiveDecommissionWhen="90"/>
    [wladm] </runtime>

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dbasedir=/Users/olivieri/git/Ready.App.4.Perch/PerchReadyApp
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.jars.dir=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.ant.tools.dir=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/ant-tools
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.hostname=192.168.1.126
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -file=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml
mobilefirst-cli verb ant task deploy-All
Buildfile: /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml

deploy-All:

minimal-update-WAR:
[updateapplicationserver] Logging output of task <updateApplicationServer> to file /Users/olivieri/.mobilefirst_platform_server/configuration-logs/updateApplicationServer_2015_06_17_23_47_11.log
[updateapplicationserver] ** Creating migrated war file
[updateapplicationserver] Jun 17, 2015 11:47:11 PM com.worklight.ant.migration.MigrationTask MigrationTask.execute
[updateapplicationserver] INFO: FWLST2014I: The migration process was bypassed, because the project WAR file of version 7.0.0.00.20150608-1356 is compatible with the server version 7.0.0.00.20150608-1356.
[updateapplicationserver] Jun 17, 2015 11:47:11 PM com.worklight.ant.migration.MigrationTask MigrationTask.execute
[updateapplicationserver] INFO: FWLST2015I: The project WAR file was successfully copied to the destination location '/var/folders/c9/gf_f0_sd60q1mm9kxwgvlxsr0000gn/T/wla8891032652/PerchReadyApp.war'.
[updateapplicationserver] ** Created migrated war file
[updateapplicationserver] Copying /var/folders/c9/gf_f0_sd60q1mm9kxwgvlxsr0000gn/T/wla8891032652/PerchReadyApp.war to /Users/olivieri/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.0.0.00.20150608-1356/server/wlp/usr/servers/worklight/apps/PerchReadyApp.war

deploy-Adapters:
     [echo] Deploy MobileFirst adapters for project PerchReadyApp
     [echo] Deploying MobileFirst Adapter /Users/olivieri/git/Ready.App.4.Perch/PerchReadyApp/bin/AuthenticationAdapter.adapter to http://192.168.1.126:10080/worklightadmin
     [echo] Username admin
mobilefirst-cli verb cli finish with mobilefirst restart
mobilefirst-cli verb code 1

**MFP CLI v7.0 bd output:**
$ mfp bd -d
All apps and adapters were successfully built.
$
```

Answer (score 1):

So maybe semantic, but you can't have a 6.3 project with v7.0 CLI.  The first command you run within that project will force an automatic upgrade to the level of the CLI.

I'm unable to replicate your issue using a basic test case.

MFP v6.3

1. create and start server
2. create project and adapter
3. build, deploy, test adapter ok
4. stop server

MFP 7.0

1. create and start v7.0 server
2. [Project is automatically upgraded to v7.0]
3. build, deploy, test adapter ok

Please PM me your project, or a subset that replicates the issue, and I'll dig further, and/or get development involved.